# Equation in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, canopy-height-model

Recently I have derived a correlation equation between biomass and canopy height using sample tree parameters from field. The equation is

```
       Biomass = 0.0001(Height)^ 2.895.
```

I tried to calculate the biomass using the height derived from my Canopy Height Model (CHM) using the following code,

```
     var Biomass = CHMfinal.exp(2.895).multiply(0.0001).rename('AGB')
```

where, CHMfinal is my height data

but this is not working and giving me an error saying

```
   'Too many (2) arguments to function: Image.exp(value)

   Computes the Euler's number e raised to the power of the input.

 Args:

    value (Image): The image to which the operation is applied.
      in <global>, line 274
      in <global>, line 276'
```

Can anyone say where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`.exp()` computes the "Euler's number e raised to the power of the input" and does not take an any arguments.

What you want to do is I guess

```js
var Biomass = CHMfinal.pow(ee.Number(2.895))
```

or if CHMfinal is an image

```js
var Biomass = CHMfinal.pow(ee.Image(2.895))
```